# Use jQuery to select, then use YUI to animate? Good idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, yui3

jQuery's animation engine isn't working well for me. It doesn't have easing and color animation built-in, and the plugins I am using for them don't work properly together consistently.

I've had good experience with YUI's animation engine in the past. Is it possible to use jQuery to select items, and then use YUI to animate them? Here's my current jQuery-animated code to animate a div when you click it:

```
$("div.article").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).children(".box").animate({height:'+=100px', paddingTop: '24px'},300);   
    $(this).children(".box").children(".subBoxA").show().animate({opacity: "1"}, 500);  
});
```

How would I go about converting the animations in this function to YUI3?

(Is this even a good idea? Should I just convert *everything* to YUI3, selectors and all? Also, if this comes across as a dumb question, forgive me, i'm a noob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are animating a single element, you can do something like this:

```
YUI.use("anim", function (Y) {
    $("div.article").mousedown(function () {
        var el = $(this).children(".box")[0],
            anim;
        anim = new Y.Anim({
            node: el,
            /* animation configuration */
        });
        anim.run();
    });
});
```

AFAIK, YUI does not support animating multiple elements out of the box, though you could implement it using the tween events.

I suspect you are better off using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/), however.  It provides color animation and advanced easing.

Comment: Thank you very much. This example explained so much about how to use jQuery and YUI together. I really appreciate it. And thanks for showing me jQuery UI! This has basically solved all the problems I was having with jQuery's animation engine in the first place. Awesome! Thanks again.

Comment: I deduced from context that the questioner was already using jQuery in his code and considering adding YUI *only* for the animation module.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the benefit of these javascript libraries is that you get a ton of functionality in a smaller amount of code. By including both JQuery and YUI, you are quickly increasing the size of your pages.

If the only thing you are using jquery for is to select elements in the DOM, then definitely convert to YUI as it has many of the same selection methods. If you are using several pieces of both jquery and YUI, then mixing them may be something you have to live with for now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert. I am indeed using jQuery for more than just selection, so I'd rather not ditch it entirely.

That's my problem, though. How would I go about converting the animations in the above function to YUI3 while leaving the jQuery intact?